# PHP MySQL insert into with GET method

Tags: php, mysql, file-upload

I am trying admin panel work. I downloaded this example admin panel design: http://medialoot.com/item/html5-admin-template/

HTML structure: http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/5940949/

I tried PHP code,

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['submit'])){
    if($_FILES["carImage"]["error"] > 0){
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert('."File not upload" . $_FILES["carImage"]["error"].');</script>';
    }else{
        if(!is_dir("../inc/imj/cars")){
            mkdir("../inc/imj/cars");
        }
        $carImage_ = "../inc/imj/cars".$_FILES["carImage"]["name"];
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["carImage"]["tmp_name"],$carImage_);

        mysql_query("

        INSERT INTO contents ('indexId','catId','carModelName','carCash','carImage','carAlt','carTitle','carKMH','carWeight','carWheelInch','carColur','info')
        VALUES (NULL,'".$_GET['catId']."','".$_GET['carModelName']."','".$_GET['carCash']."','".$carImage_."','".$_GET['carAlt']."','".$_GET['carTitle']."','".$_GET['carKMH']."','".$_GET['carWeight']."','".$_GET['carWheelInch']."','".$_GET['carColur']."','".$_GET['info']."')

        ");

    }
}       
?>
```

I tried alternative query code,

```
mysql_query("

INSERT INTO contents ('indexId','catId','carModelName','carCash','carImage','carAlt','carTitle','carKMH','carWeight','carWheelInch','carColur','info')
VALUES (NULL,".$_GET['catId'].",".$_GET['carModelName'].",".$_GET['carCash'].",".$carImage_.",".$_GET['carAlt'].",".$_GET['carTitle'].",".$_GET['carKMH'].",".$_GET['carWeight'].",".$_GET['carWheelInch'].",".$_GET['carColur'].",".$_GET['info'].")

");
```

I guess file not uploading. so not working.

Because errors;

**Notice: Undefined index: carImage in ..**

**Notice: Undefined index: bilgi in ..**

**note: TABLE contents.indexId is primary key and auto increment.**

How solve we do?

Thank you for your interest.

**UPDATE**

Image upload problem is;

```
<?php
$catId = isset($_GET['catId']) ? $_GET['catId'] : "";
$carModelName = isset($_GET['carModelName']) ? $_GET['carModelName'] : "";
$carCash = isset($_GET['carCash']) ? $_GET['carCash'] : "";
$carAlt = isset($_GET['carAlt']) ? $_GET['carAlt'] : "";
$carTitle = isset($_GET['carTitle']) ? $_GET['carTitle'] : "";
$carKMH = isset($_GET['carKMH']) ? $_GET['carKMH'] : "";
$carWeight = isset($_GET['carWeight']) ? $_GET['carWeight'] : "";
$carWheelInch = isset($_GET['carWheelInch']) ? $_GET['carWheelInch'] : "";
$carColur = isset($_GET['carColur']) ? $_GET['carColur'] : "";
$info = isset($_GET['info']) ? $_GET['info'] : "";
if(isset($_GET['submit'])){
    if($_FILES["carImage"]["error"] > 0){
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert('."File not upload" . $_FILES["carImage"]["error"].');</script>';
    }else{

        $carUrl_ = "../inc/imj/urun";
        if(!is_dir($carUrl_)){mkdir($carUrl_);}

        $carImage_ = $carUrl_.$_FILES["carImage"]["name"];
        $carUrlName = $_FILES["carImage"]["name"];
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["carImage"]["tmp_name"],$carImage_);

        mysql_query("

        INSERT INTO contents ('indexId','catId','carModelName','carCash','carImage','carAlt','carTitle','carKMH','carWeight','carWheelInch','carColur','info')
        VALUES (".$catId.",".$_GET['carModelName'].",".$_GET['carCash'].",".$carUrlName.",".$carAlt.",".$carTitle.",".$carKMH.",".$carWeight.",".$carWheelInch.",".$carColur.",".$info.")

        ");

    }
}       
?>
```

**Update 2**

```
<?php
$catId = isset($_GET['catId']) ? $_GET['catId'] : "";
$carModelName = isset($_GET['carModelName']) ? $_GET['carModelName'] : "";
$carCash = isset($_GET['carCash']) ? $_GET['carCash'] : "";
$carAlt = isset($_GET['carAlt']) ? $_GET['carAlt'] : "";
$carTitle = isset($_GET['carTitle']) ? $_GET['carTitle'] : "";
$carKMH = isset($_GET['carKMH']) ? $_GET['carKMH'] : "";
$carWeight = isset($_GET['carWeight']) ? $_GET['carWeight'] : "";
$carWheelInch = isset($_GET['carWheelInch']) ? $_GET['carWheelInch'] : "";
$carColur = isset($_GET['carColur']) ? $_GET['carColur'] : "";
$info = isset($_GET['info']) ? $_GET['info'] : "";
if(isset($_GET['submit'])){

        mysql_query("

        INSERT INTO contents ('indexId','catId','carModelName','carCash','carImage','carAlt','carTitle','carKMH','carWeight','carWheelInch','carColur','info')
        VALUES (".$catId.",".$_GET['carModelName'].",".$_GET['carCash'].",tryImg.png,".$carAlt.",".$carTitle.",".$carKMH.",".$carWeight.",".$carWheelInch.",".$carColur.",".$info.")

        ");

}       
?>
```

Comment: I think you are better off using POST in place of GET here. Have you tried that ?

Comment: Also, are you sure the error is in MySQL query? Could the error be in some other part of the code ?

Comment: I can not add rows to the table with INSERT INTO method.

Comment: @Maximus2012 single file.

Comment: From where are getting the value of bilgi? It does not seem to be there in your code.

Comment: I don't see value as the bilgi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each variable in get, check if the variable was set before using it in mysql insert statement.

```
$variable = (isset($_GET['variable'])) ? $_GET['variable'] : "";
```

And do not insert indexId, it will be incremented automatically, you can just drop it from query statement.

```
mysql_query("

INSERT INTO contents ('catId','carModelName','carCash','carImage','carAlt','carTitle','carKMH','carWeight','carWheelInch','carColur','info')
VALUES (".$_GET['catId'].",".$_GET['carModelName'].",".$_GET['carCash'].",".$carImage_.",".$_GET['carAlt'].",".$_GET['carTitle'].",".$_GET['carKMH'].",".$_GET['carWeight'].",".$_GET['carWheelInch'].",".$_GET['carColur'].",".$_GET['info'].")

");
```

**Update**

When a user leave a field empty,

```
isset($_GET['that-field'])
```

returns false, i.e. value not set.

else isset returns true, i.e. user set the value for that variable.

So you cannot use $_GET['var'] without knowing var was given some value or not.
If user did not give any value, you will have to set it yourself before entering it to database.

So use,

```
if(isset($_GET['variable'])){
   $variable = $_GET['variable'];
} else{
   $variable = "";
}
```

You will have to do it for all variables, before you run the mysql query, and use `'$variable'` there instead of `$_GET['variable']`.

Comment: I did like this;

if(isset($_GET['catId']) || isset($_GET['carModelName']) || isset($_GET['carCash']) || isset($_GET['carAlt']) || isset($_GET['carTitle']) || isset($_GET['carKMH']) || isset($_GET['carWeight']) || isset($_GET['carWheelInch']) || isset($_GET['carColour']) || isset($_GET['info'])){//query and file upload settings..}

Bu I didn't work.. :/

Comment: You should be using `&&` instead of `||`. Right? And if any of them hasn't been set, you want to discard everything?

Comment: Ok. No mistakes this time. but not adding. I just want to add informations to the table..

Comment: You have done if(..). Also add else condition to it. `else{echo "There were some not set input values, so your data cannot be added";}`

Comment: No, I saw you added "There were some not set input values, so your data cannot be added"..

Comment: Okey, sorry I don't saw. I did. The only problem is image upload. 
**Notice: Undefined index: carImage in ..**

Comment: add your new code to the question, as an update after the current question

Comment: @fthmad9 Are you uploading an image using a form to this page?

Comment: so single file, this file name is index.php. index.php in form and php, sending self params(index.php).

Comment: @fthmad9 sorry what are you asking?

Comment: not adding row. So, I guess file not uplaoding. How do we do? File not uploading. I am working xampp so localhost..

Comment: Hi, I came. I did what you said. File upload section is close it. But not to add data contents table. Maybe corrected, so I do replace GET to POST. but the same.

Comment: The data is not added to table.

Comment: You will have too use `'".$variable."'`.  You are missing the ' '.