# How to store data in mysql with php using GET method?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to store the data from php to mysql using GET method ,

```
   <?php 
    $user = "root";
    $password = "";
    $host = "localhost";

    $connection = mysql_connect($host,$user,$password);
    $select = mysql_select_db('dam',$connection);

    if($connection)
    {
        echo "connection succesfull";
    }
    else {
        echo "Error";
    }
 ?>
```

this is the Database connection code connection.php and also it shows connectionsucccesfull in localhos (browser) and i am trying to add some data to database using GET method

```
    <?php 
    include("connect.php");

    $sensor1 = $_GET['sensor1'];
    $sensor2 = $_GET['sensor2'];
    $sensor3 = $_GET['sensor3'];



    $sql_insert = "insert into tablearduino (sensor1,sensor2,sensor3) values ('$sensor1,$sensor2,$sensor3')";

    mysql_query($sql_insert);

    if($sql_insert)
    {
        echo "Saving succeed";
    }
    else{
        echo "Error occured";
    }
 ?>
```

when i type the url like this

> http://localhost/EPPF/index.php?sensor1=5.0&sensor2=3.0&sensor3=4.0

data is not storing in mysql database

**What is the problem and how can i fix it ?**

Comment: Your insert query should be like this `values ('$sensor1','$sensor2','$sensor3')`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP MySQL insert into with GET method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18023440/php-mysql-insert-into-with-get-method)

Comment: Do not use `mysql`. Use `mysqli`. Check my answer with prepared statements.

Comment: also using `GET` method is insecure. Always use `POST`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your query to

```
$sql_insert = "insert into tablearduino (sensor1,sensor2,sensor3) values ('$sensor1','$sensor2','$sensor3')";
```

Answer (score 1):

change your query from

```
$sql_insert = "insert into tablearduino (sensor1,sensor2,sensor3) values ('$sensor1,$sensor2,$sensor3')";
```

to

```
$sql_insert = "insert into tablearduino (sensor1,sensor2,sensor3) values ('".$sensor1."','".$sensor2."','".$sensor3."')";
```

I don't know about the datatype you have assigned to these fields, so i assuming it to varchar

Answer (score 1):

Change your query

### FROM

```
$sql_insert = "insert into tablearduino (sensor1,sensor2,sensor3) values ('$sensor1,$sensor2,$sensor3')";
```

### To

```
$sql_insert = "insert into tablearduino (sensor1,sensor2,sensor3) values ('$sensor1','$sensor2','$sensor3')";
```

Use single quotes with varibale name because its is string.
If it is flot or integer column in your database table then you can use it directly (without single quotes)

```
 $sql_insert = "insert into tablearduino (sensor1,sensor2,sensor3) values ($sensor1,$sensor2,$sensor3)";
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an error is your query
The query is below

```
insert into tablearduino (sensor1,sensor2,sensor3) values ('".$sensor1."','".$sensor2."','".$sensor3."')"
```

Answer (score 0):

you are writing wrong the query
your query is

```
$sql_insert = "insert into tablearduino (sensor1,sensor2,sensor3) values ('$sensor1,$sensor2,$sensor3')";
```

where it should be

```
$sql_insert = "insert into tablearduino (sensor1,sensor2,sensor3) values ('{$sensor1}','{$sensor2}','{$sensor3}')";
```

mind the quotes locations